# Javascript object from Jquery object

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to understand this code.
    //...

```
obj.dd.on('click', function(event){
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    return false;
});

//...

$(function() {

    var dd = new DropDown( $('#dd') );

    $(document).click(function() {
        // all dropdowns
        $('.wrapper-dropdown-1').removeClass('active');
    });

});
```

What is exactly is going on when you pass the jquery object into the constructor of a javascript object?

Also what is the obj in the obj.dd that the on method is called on?

Comment: You would have to show the code for `DropDown` and `obj`.

Comment: Presumably `obj.dd` is a jQuery object, because the `.on` method wouldn't work otherwise.

Comment: I guess your `Dropdown` method has something like this: `this.dd = dd;`(dd is the passed in jquery object). Your `obj` is created using something like `var obj = new Dropdown($('#dd'));`. If that's the case, `obj.dd` is your passed in jQuery object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is exactly is going on when you pass the jquery object into the constructor of a javascript object?

You're calling a constructor function with an argument. That's all. Anything else that happens depends on the definition of the `DropDown` function.

There is nothing special about a jQuery object. It is just like any other JavaScript object. It just happens to have been created using some third party JavaScript.

> Also what is the obj in the obj.dd that the on method is called on?

We can't tell. You haven't shown us the code that defines it. It must be defined elsewhere on the page.

Comment: Not really sure why this is getting downvotes. Looks like a solid explanation to me.

Comment: No real reason for it to get upvotes too!

Comment: Right, I see. It was just that the code was presented as if implying is was self contained, which is where the confusion came from. Thanks.